# Express the following code in r: rbind(data[1,]),data[2,],....,data[i,])

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rbind

I face a difficulty  expressing the following code in R. The basic idea is that I want to r(ow)bind every row element in a data frame, like this way:

```
#transpose every horizontal element into a single vertical column 
#notice: the value for "length(data[,1])" is large so that cant work with sth like rbind(A,B,C,D) 
#let's say: data<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:100000,nrow=5000,ncol=20, byrow=F))

for(i in 1:length(data[,1])){
trans<-rbind(t(data[1,]),t(data[2,]),....,t(data[i,]))
}
```

Or

```
for(i in 1:length(data[,1])){
trans<-rbind(t(data[1:i,]))}
```

Or

```
for(i in 1:length(data[,1])){
trans<-rbind(t(data[c(1:i),]))}
```

But none of these work.

Comment: Why? That will just return your data.frame again.

Comment: @Jacob Green I updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to a single column from your dataset:

```
 dat1 <- data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=6:10, Col3=11:15)
 as.data.frame(matrix(t(dat1)))
 #   V1
 #1   1
 #2   6
 #3  11
 #4   2
 #5   7
 #6  12
 #7   3
 #8   8
 #9  13
 #10  4
 #11  9
 #12 14
 #13  5
 #14 10
 #15 15
```

Or

```
 data.frame(V1=c(t(dat1)))
```

#### Update

You could do:

```
 newdata <- vector('numeric')
 for(i in seq_len(nrow(dat1))){ newdata <-c(newdata, unlist(dat1[i,], use.names=FALSE))}
 as.data.frame(newdata)
```

Comment: thank u sir..i really appreciate.. i have one more question.. is there any way i can code the following in a correct way: for(i in 1:1000){newdata<-cbind(data(1),data(2),...,data(i))}

Comment: @Jacob Green Based on the dataset, I provided, what will be the expected result?  Thanks.  Also, data(1) means what ?  Is it column or row for the data?

Comment: data(1) is column....or could be vector as well..actually it does not matter. the thing that i hope to know is that how to code sth like ",....," in the code above... ( of course your answer is the one that i am looking for..thank u so much)